# How to map data in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to map data in the model.

For example, I have a `Plan` model which has a field called `value`. Then I in the `param` we have `{value: "unlimited"}`, `{value: "1"}`,..., etc.

I want to store `nil` to database when it is `unlimited`, and store `int` when value is digit.
I also want to have a validation when the value is not `unlimited` or `digit`.

In addition, when I display the data in view, I need show `unlimited` when it's nil.

What's the best way to do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override default setter:

```
def value=val
    if val == 'unlimited'
        self[:value] = nil
    else
        super val
    end
end
```

And default getter:

```
def value
    super||'unlimited'
end
```

And add conditional validation:

```
validates :value, numericality: { only_integer: true }, unless: -> {value == 'unlimited'}
```

Comment: Look like a good idea. Do you have any idea if I need to use the value to do calculation. For instance, calculate left. (when it's unlimited, the left: unlimited - used = unlimited)